# Using java reflection to set field through its setter method

Tags: java, reflection

Assume my class I have a field name called

```
private long _quantity;
```

I have created a getter and a setter for it (e.g. `getQty` and `setQty`).

Is there a way in Java reflection when I use `field.set(...)` to force it to go through its setter?

I just read up on a tag @Access...does any one have experience with using @Access? can it be used to force a field access into a method?

Comment: Field name should correspond to the method names and vice versa.

Comment: why do people insist on using an underscore (or similar) for field names!?

Comment: @Robert Also present in C# design guidelines. It looks like the underscore scares the hell out of people so they won't touch private variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,  if you want to call your setter, you'll need to call that method and not set the field directly.

If you have a handle on the field itself, `set` will not go through your method.

Answer (score 2):

No. The whole point of reflection is that you are essentially removing the safety belts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you the field name corresponds to a getter/setter methods, perhaps you could use the getDeclaredMethods, find out the correct method and use it?
See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with reflection. The only technology on the Java VM that I am aware of that does something similar is AspectJ, it lets you register aspects that [intercept field access](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e4790). But even that won't work with reflection.